# Is redirecting output with > redundant when using slurm?

Tags: redirect, slurm

I am running my program with slurm. I want all output (and all errors) to go to logfile.log. My sbatch script is

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=logfile.log
#SBATCH --error=logfile.log

srun PROGRAM
```

I assume that this will behave identically if I changed the run line to `srun PROGRAM > logfile.log` and I am already catching all output and errors. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a submission script such as

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output=logfile.log
#SBATCH --error=logfile.log

srun PROGRAM > logfile.log
```

the `logfile.log` will be created by Slurm at the beginning of the job, and then truncated at the start of the `srun` command.

What you might loose in the process is any message written out during prologs if any. Other than that, it should be ok,  but there may be some corner cases where it could fail and is therefore probably not a good practice.